# Cloud Foundry: update WAR without reverting server.xml

Tags: java, maven, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

With Bluemix / Cloud Foundry, is there any way to deploy an application Java WAR (only the WAR) without reverting server.xml to the default value?

I have a datasource for an external database in my server.xml and after each build, the war file is generated by Maven and pushed/updated to Bluemix by [Maven Cloud Foundry](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/tree/master/cloudfoundry-maven-plugin) plugin. After the WAR is pushed, the server profile reverts to the default value and the datasource configuration is gone.

I know that the recommended way is to push the usr/server directory or zip file, but I would like to continue to use Maven CF plugin to simplify the build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure maven to push the server package by configuring `path` to point the zip.

`$ mvn cf:push [-Dcf.appname=APPNAME] [-Dcf.path=PATH]`

Comment: If I go this way, I would need to have server.xml in my code base, with the datasource configuration hard coded, right? Unless server.xml could reference system properties from Bluemix.

Comment: That's right. You should define a User Defined service `cf uups` with the db credentials. When you bind the service to your application, you can reference those variables. See `cf files <appname> app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/runtime-vars.xml` for a full list of variables. You should also be be to reference system env variables: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_setup_vars.html